# Cannot make table row change color on hover

Tags: html, css, hover, row, css-tables

I made on hover color changer for table data but I want to change it for whole table row on hover, but it doesn't work when I change td:hover to tr:hover. What am I doing wrong?

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uwvvmpok/

HTML:

```
   <div class="content">
<div class="header">
</div>

 <a name="172016">
 <!--1. riadok H-->
 <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
 <tr>
 <th width="50px">C. u.</th>
 <th width="30px">Zobrazit</th>
 <th width="30px">Typ</th>
 <th width="200px">Cislo/Meno</th>
 <th width="600px">Popis</th>
 <th width="130px">System</th>
 <th width="100px">Dopad/Symptom</th>
 <th width="100px">Dátum zadania</th>
 <th width="100px">Dátum vzniku</th>
 <th width="100px">Datum Verifikacie</th>
 <th width="80px">Ukoncenie</th>
 <th width="500px">Komentár</th>
 <th width="100px">Dátum</th>
 <th width="60px">Počet</th>
</tr>
<!--2. riadok D-->
<tr>
 <td style="text-align:center;background-color: #d0f5f6">100</td>
 <td style="text-align:center">X</td>
 <td style="text-align:center">C </td>
 <td>DOBRIKOVA/DURACKA</td>
 <td class="tooltip">Gefco PC nasa siet CD vs finalne riesenie internet  gefco pc CORAIL <span class="ttext">ked sa vytvara uplne novu hypotheza tak nefunguje vyber tlaciarni a globalny export tiez NOK (nepouzivame)</span> </td>
 <td>CORAIL/CONSO</td>
 <td></td>
 <td class="DZ">06/07/2016</td>
 <td class="DZ">06/07/2016</td>
 <td class="DZ">06/07/2016</td>
 <td style="text-align:center">OK</td>
 <td>ked sa vytvara uplne novu hypotheza tak nefunguje vyber tlaciarni a globalny export tiez NOK (nepouzivame)</td>
 <td style="text-align:center">07/07/2016</td>
 <td style="text-align:center">2</td>
</tr>
```

CSS:

```
.content {
position: static;
}

.header {
text-align: center;
position: relative;
margin-top: 40px;
}


th, td{
 border:1px solid black;
overflow: hidden;
}

th{
background-color: #eff0f0;  
}

td{
background-color: #eed6b1;
height: 50px;
}
table{
table-layout: fixed;
min-width: 2000px;
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
margin-left: 5px;
}

.DZ {
text-align: center;
}


td:hover{
background-color: #b0b0b0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the background color of the `td` when the row is hovered.

```
tr:hover td {
    background: #b0b0b0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j0aj1p80/

Comment: To overwrite the green first cell, remove the inline styling. https://jsfiddle.net/6efsbobj/